# Font doesn't show until window resize in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webpack, font-face

I'm using angular2 and webpack. Loading my font like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bpmonoregular';
  src: url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.eot');
  src: url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.svg#bpmonoregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If in my css I increase the font-size percentage the font won't show up unless its the first component loaded. As soon as I switch pages, it disappears. If I resize the window however, it will show up.

This only happens in chrome

Comment: Hey there, I suspect my Chrome have the same problem as you. Is there any chance you can replicate your issue somewhere I can play with?

Comment: Windows 10 OS ?

Comment: We experience the same bug as well in a very big application. It started after upgrading to full (non-beta) version of Angular 2 or after upgrading to webpack 2 (we are not sure what has caused it). Anyway, we haven't found a solution to the problem you are describing (some text does not show until you resize the window, or manually modify css using developer tools).

Comment: Hi I'm experiencing the same issue on the latest version of Angular, has anyone found a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to fire a window.resize with code on document.ready as a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load font-face using static css (style tag or link) instead of component styles.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome utilises the `.svg` file in the `@font-face kit`, and it shouldn't be called last. Try re-arranging your code like that:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'bpmonoregular';
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.svg#bpmonoregular') format('svg'),
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  src: url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.eot');
  src: url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Put `url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.svg#bpmonoregular') format('svg')` on the first line.

The main solution was found here on this website: [Font Face Rendering on Chrome](https://www.adtrak.co.uk/font-face-chrome-rendering/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it without

```
 font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting webkit browsers to load the font from only the `svg` source

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: ‘bpmonoregular’;
    src: url('assets/fonts/bpmono_regular_macroman/BPmono-webfont.svg#bpmonoregular') format(‘svg’);
  }
}
```

[In depth article here](https://www.adtrak.co.uk/font-face-chrome-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your font as .woff and import it like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontName";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("/persist/fonts/FontName.woff") format("woff");
}
```